# How to filter array of objects by object keys?

Tags: javascript

I try to filter array of object `items` by keys `fields`:

```
const items = [{id: 1, name: "OP"}];
const fields = ['id', 'name'];
const value = 1;

   return items.filter((singleItem) => {
      fields.forEach((field) => {
        singleItem[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
      })
    })
```

But How to return found result back to filter?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducable example...

Comment: Done, you can check it

Comment: What are you trying to keep? Objects that have all the properties in `fields`, or just some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const items = [{id: 1, name: "OP"}];
const fields = ['id', 'name'];
const value = 1;

const result = items.filter(item =>
  fields.some(field =>
    ('' + item[field]).toLowerCase().includes(('' + value).toLowerCase())));
  
console.log(result);
```

Considering that your original logic had a case conversion and a call to `includes()`, I'm converting everything to strings by appending to `''`.

---

From a DRY perspective, it would probably be nicer to split off the canonicalization into a separate function:

```js
const items = [{id: 1, name: "OP"}];
const fields = ['id', 'name'];
const value = 1;

const canonicalize = (x) => ('' + x).toLowerCase();

const result = items.filter(item =>
  fields.some(field =>
    canonicalize(item[field]).includes(canonicalize(value))));
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ideal use case for [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). Also, the `return` keyword is missing in your snippet.

I have used `toString()` to convert all the inputs to `string` before invoking `toLowerCase` method as it does not work on `Number`.

```js
let items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "abc"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "xyz"
}];
let fields = ['id', 'name'];
let value = 'xyz';

let op = items.filter((singleItem) => {
  return fields.find((field) => singleItem[field].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
});

console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (or maybe [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) depending on your required output).

> [`some`] returns true if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function returns true; otherwise it returns false.

Instead of `includes` I would use a direct comparison. Additionally you can't call `toLowerCase` on a number. You could coerce it to a string and then check it against the lowercase value, but in this example I've left that out. I think the value you pass into the function should be the correct type that you look for in the objects.

```js
const items = [{id: 1, name: 'OP'},{id: 2, name: 'OP'}];
const fields = ['id', 'name'];

function fn(value) {
  return items.filter(item => {
    return Object.values(item).some(v => {
      return v === value;
    });
  })
}

console.log(fn(1));
console.log(fn('1'));
console.log(fn('OP'));
```

Additional documentation

- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)